# How to duplicate MySQL fields?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, field

On the admin panel of my website, I have a page to add a new product to the DB. After the product is added to the DB, it will have the following structure:

```
item_id  | item_name | item_price
   1         name1       1.00
   2         name2       2.00
             (...)
   5         name5       5.00
```

This page (that I use to add new products) is called "new.php".
I have created a page where I can view the products that I have added (called "index.php"), and a delete button so that I can, of course, delete an item.

I want now create another button, this time to duplicate a product. I have had some ideas, but they all proved to be wrong.

To exemplify, let's say that I want to duplicate the item_id 2. So my table would be like this:

```
item_id  | item_name | item_price
   1         name1       1.00
   2         name2       2.00
             (...)
   5         name5       5.00
   6         name2       2.00
```

It's valid to note that the item_id is auto_increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl (item_name, item_price)
SELECT item_name, item_price FROM tbl WHERE item_id = 2
```

Comment: @Sinner: that is because you did something wrong, since the query is syntactically correct. Give an exaplnation what `didn't work` means.

Comment: Actually, when I tried the way you said, it did nothing, just loaded the index.php page with no duplicate. Then I tried to use SELECT * and (of course) it shows the error: Duplicate entry '1397' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: @Sinner: that is why I did specify only **necessary** fields. `item_id` is a primary key and supposed to be unique. So you need to enumerate all fields except PK (or other unique)

Comment: I accessed the DB via phpMyAdmin and I see that every time I click on "duplicate", a new ID is created, but none of the other fields are duplicated. It shows this way: item_id='7', item_name='', item_price=''.];

Comment: @Sinner: it is not possible with **my** query.

Comment: I'm not saying your query is wrong. All I'm saying is what is happening. What could be causing this?

Comment: @Sinner: I'm too bored already to guess. Give the **exact** query you're performing and **exact** table schema. (add them to your initial question)

Comment: @Sinner: What `"SELECT id_parceiro, oferta, porque, regras, valor, desconto, maximo, datainicio, datafim, imagem, compradores, minimo, validade, limite, prioridade, tags, senha, pendencia, pendentes, adesivo FROM $nometabela WHERE id=$id" returns? How many rows with what data? PS: **there is no id field in the table description**

Comment: I forgot to put the id field there. How do I see what results it returns?

Comment: @Sinner: JUST PERFORM IT IN PMA. Are you kidding? :-S

Comment: Thought you were asking something else. Nevermind, the results are okay - it is actually duplicating the field on the database. I guess the problem lies within the php now. Thanks for the help.